# How do I show the schema of a table in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, schema, database-schema

From the [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) console, what command displays the schema of any given table?

Comment: Related, if it's of interest, I wrote a *Describe All Tables* in [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38679580).

Answer (score 669, accepted):

For formatted output:

```
describe [db_name.]table_name;
```

For an SQL statement that can be used to create a table:

```
show create table [db_name.]table_name;
```

Comment: This is not the answer. The OP is looking to figure out the "db_name" part, and this solution assumes you already know that

Comment: the OP accepted that answer 7 years ago.
I think he was happy with that answer.

Comment: Database is not a schema.

Comment: or `desc [db_name.]table_name;` for short.

Comment: In Antionio's defense, some systems refer to their collections of related tables as schemas and not databases. Not sure which or why.

Comment: Database is synonymous with schema in mysql/mariadb.

Comment: Syntax and how to use from official docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html

Comment: `.schema table_name` on sqlight

Answer (score 123):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTable;
```

or

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 23):

You can also use shorthand for describe as `desc` for table description.

> desc [db_name.]table_name;

or

> use db_name; 
>   desc table_name;

You can also use `explain` for table description.

> explain [db_name.]table_name;

See [official doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)

Will give output like:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age      | int(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sex      | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sal      | int(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| location | varchar(20) | YES  |     | Pune    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 18):

Perhaps the question needs to be slightly more precise here about what is required because it *can* be read it two different ways. i.e.

1. How do I get the structure/definition for a table in mysql?
2. How do I get the name of the schema/database this table resides in?

Given the accepted answer, the OP clearly intended it to be interpreted the first way. For anybody reading the question the other way try

```
SELECT `table_schema` 
FROM `information_schema`.`tables` 
WHERE `table_name` = 'whatever';
```

Comment: Your answer for the second point helped me for what I'm looking. My editor thrown the error saying "Invalid Object" on the table I tried to use and I have no clue about the DB or Schema under which the table falls in as the table is already created by someone else already, until I got this information

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME,table_schema
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```