# How to use mysqli_query() in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm coding in PHP. I have the following mySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Start` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `End` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I'm trying to use the [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) function in PHP to DESCRIBE the table.

Here's my code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DATABASE);
$result = mysqli_query($link,"DESCRIBE students");
```

The documentation says *For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object.*

But from there I don't know how to print `$result` so that it shows the query results. If possible I want to print $result so that it looks like:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID       | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Start    | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| End      | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My other question is how to print the query `SHOW CREATE TABLE students`.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SHOW CREATE TABLE students");
```

Comment: no help in the php manual?

Comment: I want to show the table schema. You do that by entering the command: `DESCRIBE students`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498777/how-do-i-show-the-schema-of-a-table-in-a-mysql-database

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Also see [MySQLi extension basic examples](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php), which includes an example of how to "print resulting rows".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have to admit, `mysqli_query()` manual entry doesn't contain a clean example on how to fetch multiple rows. May be it's because the routine is so routine, known to PHP folks for decades:

```
$result = $link->query("DESCRIBE students");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // to print all columns automatically:
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
        // OR to print each column separately:
        echo "<td>",$row['Field'],"</td><td>",$row['Type'],"</td>\n";
    }
}
```

In case you want to print the column titles, you have to select your data into a nested array first and then use keys of the first row:

```
// getting all the rows from the query
// note that handy feature of OOP syntax
$data = $link->query("DESC students")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// getting keys from the first row
$header = array_keys(reset($data));
// printing them
foreach ($header as $value) {
    echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
// finally printing the data
foreach ($data as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
}
```

Some hosts may have no support for the `fetch_all()` function. In such a case, fill the `$data` array the usual way:

```
$data = [];
$result = $link->query("DESC students");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

#### Two important notes I have to add.

1. You have to configure mysqli to throw errors automatically instead of checking them for each mysqli statement manually. To do so, add this line *before* `mysqli_connect()`:

   ```
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
   ```
2. **The most important note:** unlike `mysql_query()`, `mysqli_query()` has a very limited use. You may use this function only **if no variables are going to be used in the query.** If any PHP variable is going to be used, you should never use `mysqli_query()`, but always stick to **[prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select)**, like this:

   ```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE class=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $class);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all();
   ```

It's a bit wordy, I have to admit. In order to reduce the amount of code you can either use PDO or adopt a [simple helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) to do all the prepare/bind/execute business inside:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE class=?";
$data = prepared_select($mysqli, $sql, [$class])->fetch_all();
```