# PHP inserts into database on one user, but not on another with the same privileges

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

When my registration form tries to insert with user1 (which has been granted ALL PRIVILEGES) it works. But when I try to insert with user2 (which has also been granted ALL PRIVILEGES) it won't insert. I don't get any errors and have been troubleshooting for a couple of hours now and can't find a problem, better yet a solution.

User2 didn't have all privileges (like any sane person should do of course). When I tried granting it all privileges it still couldn't insert while user1 which has the same privileges can.

As I don't know where the problem is, I can only include the database connection code which seems to be right. If anything else is needed I'd gladly put it here.

```
$dbservername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "user1";
$dbpassword = "password1";
//$dbpassword = "password2"; (I keep this here to change users fast when troubleshooting and yes I change the username everytime)
$dbname = "database1";

$db = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
```

I expected user2 to insert into the database but it won't. I don't have any error messages.

## Privileges:

[image]

## EDIT:

I have tried running the code Martin gave and both users connect...

Comment: can you share the complete script? with user2 insert

Comment: show the list of privileges given for user1 and user2.

Comment: PHP file: https://pastebin.com/2n9YaTx5

Comment: As I've said in the question itself, they normally wouldn't have the same privileges. But when I started troubleshooting I temporarily gave them both the same privileges to check if it would work then, when it didn't I asked the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to give yourself error feedback:

```
$dbServerName = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "user1";
$dbPassword = "password1";
$dbName = "database1";

    $mysqliDriver = new \mysqli_driver();
    $mysqliDriver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT;

    try {
        $db = new \mysqli($dbServerName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
    }
    catch(\mysqli_sql_exception | \Exception $em) { // format requires PHP 7.2
        error_log(print_r($em,true)); // READ THIS!!! 
        die("failed. Check the error log!");
    }
    die("We are connected!");
```

This sets up a MySQLi Driver reporting mode which can give i) Exception reporting and ii) more informative/easier to access reasons for failure.

Please let us know (**Update/Edit** your question) what the error reporting catches when connecting with User2.

NOTE:
If you do not have PHP7.2 running replce that line with:

```
catch(\Exception $em)
```

## NOTE:

Your pastebin code; you are creating the $db as a PHP *object* but are using it with static commands (`mysqli_query($db, $sql)` etc.) as if it was not an object (*procedural*). This is inconsistent and will give you issues.

[**Plese read here how to correctly structure your PHP / SQL interface**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32770532/3536236)

Comment: I have edited the question and added the results. Nothing special so far, as for your note; I'm pretty new to SQL and more advanced PHP so I don't really understand how to fix the consistency.

Comment: @Shmotten if my code runs ok and solves your problem please +1 and tick the tick. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it weird that this fixed the problem? It was just a test... however it did work so thank you anyways!

Comment: I've just tested it again and it doesn't insert, while I thought it did.

Comment: @Shmotten you seem to be missing the point -- my answer is not a full answer, it is a request to check that the basic connection works. If you DO NOT get an exception error when loading the above code; then it works and your Username/Password on MySQL is NOT the issue.

Comment: I stll maintain your issue may well be actually using OO and Procedural MySQLi on the same object. *This* needs to be fixed.

Comment: Yeah I get it now, it doesn't seem to be a username/password problem. But what could be the problem? Is it the other issue you mentioned? Because I don't really understand how to fix it.