# How to get consecutive numbers using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to **retrieve the consecutive numbers and its counts**, for example in my db **i have inputs like**

```
1,2,3,4,5,9,10,12,14,15,16,51,81
```

**I expected output**

```
Numbers         counts
  1-5              5
  9-10             2
 12-16             4
   51              1
   81              1
```

Please share the solution if anyone knows....

Comment: [Show your table structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498777/how-do-i-show-the-schema-of-a-table-in-a-mysql-database)

Comment: I have one column like studentId in my table, In that column the values are not continuous fully some break points are there(break point means some value are missing for example 1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,15,23 like that). so i want to get the count how many continuous are in that table and that no starting point and ending point

Comment: FWIW, this strikes me as something that is challenging to do in a SQL query, but would be quite easy to do in backend code with, say, PHP.

Comment: @CatoMinor Funny, that I think, it's the other way round...easy to do in sql, tedious to do in PHP...

Comment: @fancyPants sounds like you're writing us a solution, even as I type? `:-D`

Comment: Hm, maybe my opinion comes from me being a database admin and having no clue, how to approach this in PHP :-D And now I noticed there are more implications than I first expected, but it's still doable.

Comment: This is not feasible in SQL. Use your backend code like PHP or C#.

Comment: If any one known please share the PHP code for that solution

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes It is feasible ;-) see my answer, if you like.

Comment: @Martin I did :-D

Comment: I know I should've used "undesirable" instead. I usually prefer to tell people something's not doable instead because otherwise they might try, and this code will end up running some mission-critical production application somewhere where I have to clean it up in 5 years.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Hm, good point. Haven't thought about that :-)

Answer (score 3):

*DISCLAIMER: This is for the fun of it. It may be easier to use an actual programming language of your choice.*

This is not as easy as it first looks, you have to use [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (9),
    (10),
    (12),
    (14),
    (15),
    (16),
    (51),
    (81)
;
```

Query:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', MIN(id), IF(MAX(id) = MIN(ID), NULL, MAX(id))), COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT 
id
, @group_number := IF(@prev != id - 1, @group_number + 1, @group_number) AS gn
, @prev := id
FROM 
t,
(SELECT @group_number := 0, @prev := NULL) var_init_subquery
ORDER BY id
) sq
GROUP BY gn
```

Result:

```
| CONCAT_WS('-', MIN(id), IF(MAX(id) = MIN(ID), NULL, MAX(id))) | COUNT(*) |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|----------|
|                                                           1-5 |        5 |
|                                                          9-10 |        2 |
|                                                            12 |        1 |
|                                                         14-16 |        3 |
|                                                            51 |        1 |
|                                                            81 |        1 |
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/164b2d/5)

Comment: Hi, this is great, but is there a way to make it distinct?

Answer (score 0):

```
+-----------------------+----------+
| cheque_no Ascending 1 | COUNT(*) |
+-----------------------+----------+
| 0                     |        1 |
| 69843-69867           |       25 |
| 69867-69919           |       53 |
| 69919-69922           |        4 |
| 69922-69923           |        2 |
| 69923-69924           |        2 |
| 69924-69925           |        2 |
| 69925-69926           |        2 |
| 69926-69929           |        4 |
| 69929-69930           |        2 |
| 69930-69931           |        2 |
| 69931-69932           |        2 |
| 69932-69936           |        5 |
| 69936-69937           |        2 |
| 69937-70000           |       64 |
| 74101-74106           |        6 |
| 74108-74148           |       41 |
+-----------------------+----------+
```

Although after reading the disclaimer, i might just do that. Just need a rush option for now