# SQL Query Help - Bad Data Format Workaround?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've always been terrible at queries since db class and now I need to extract some data for work. Here is a sample of how the data I was given was formatted. I already transposed it so Workbench would import.

[sample-data-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btp1W.png)

What I need to query for are all of the non-zero values so I can generate a report that has itemName, date used, and # of times used.

I did a COUNTIF in Excel and there are apparently 90 non-zero values in the data. The query `SELECT * FROM myData WHERE "insert-any-column" <> 0` returns the entire table.

Any hints towards how to approach this would be awesome.

EDIT: Schema is exactly what you see in the sample image above.

Table: myData

Columns: itemName, 1/1/17, 1/2/17, etc.

Comment: Where *what* `<> 0`? You haven't specified a column.

Comment: Sorry, meant to put an "insert-any-column" != 0, I tried for any column and still get back the entire table

Comment: There's no "across multiple columns" `WHERE` clause in MySQL. You'll have to do `WHERE (foo <> 0 OR bar <> 0 OR meh <> 0)`.

Comment: (and make sure the data you're searching is numeric - `<>` against a string won't get you the results you think)

Comment: Yes, you're right? I tried many different columns and still get the entire table back

Comment: Please add your table schema to the question, then.

Comment: That's not a table schema. Show us [the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498777/how-do-i-show-the-schema-of-a-table-in-a-mysql-database) of `SHOW CREATE TABLE myData`. I'm particularly interested in the data *types* of your columns. If your column names are literally stuff like `1/1/17` you're also probably setting things up very *wrong*.

Comment: That's what I just gave you? I assumed the data type was self explanatory. itemName varchar(255) NOT NULL, 1/1/17 int(11) DEFAULT NULL, etc.

I was given the data this way and I'm looking to see if anyone knows a way to go around the terrible formatting before I go reformatting the data myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myData WHERE your_column <> 0
```

Please note that you may need to use

```
SELECT * FROM myData WHERE your_column IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: sorry I meant to write that I tried any column and still get the whole table back

Comment: did you try 

SELECT * FROM myData WHERE your_column <> ''
?

Comment: check this link to improve your question to a MCVE @raccoon_nine: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: oh, this is great, thanks! wasn't even aware there was a sqlfiddle