# SQL insert into dont let me insert in more than 20 column

Tags: php, sql

my problem is why sql doesn't let me make an insert into for a row with more than 20 column everythings works fine but when it reaches its limit()

```
$statement=$connection->prepare("INSERT INTO post
        ( id, short_name, title, fecha, author_id, 
          platform, general, size, type, views, 
          about, spain, english, japanese, italian, 
          french, other, genre, tutorial)
 VALUES ( :id, :short_name, :title, :fecha, :author_id, 
          :platform, :general, :size, :type, :views, 
          :about, :spain, :english, :japanese, :italian, 
          :french, :other, :genre, :tutorial)");

 $statement->execute(array(
               ':id'=>$null,
               ':short_name'=>$short_title,
               ':title'=>$title,
               ':fecha'=>$date,
               ':author_id'=>$mineid,
               ':platform'=>$platform,
               ':general'=>$general,
               ':size'=>$size,
               ':type'=>$type,
               ':views'=>$o,
               ':about'=>$about,
               ':spain'=>$spanish,
               ':english'=>$english,
               ':japanese'=>$japanese,
               ':italian'=>$italian,
               ':french'=>$french,
               ':other'=>$other,
               ':genre'=>$genre,
               ':tutorial'=>$videotutorial
              ));
```

When i try to add another column it just does not insert the data without telling me any error "IS THE PDO METHOD" i really need your help

Comment: What is the column name you are trying to add to this list?

Comment: pic_1, pic_2 (etc)  10 columns left

Comment: And what is contained in those columns? A full image or a path to an image on disk

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to see the schema for this table

Comment: iD primary key more than 15 column varchar(255)  ,INt columns TYNYINT(COLUMNS), LONGTEXT(COLUMNS)

Comment: HOW DO I SEND YOU THE SQL?

Comment: Numerical instances appended to a column name are usually a bad table design. You probably should have another table. Use the `edit` function of the question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51712048/edit. Add the result of `show create table post;`

Comment: Edit your question and add in the text

Comment: CREATE TABLE `post` (
 `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO

Comment: Thats what appear only that

Comment: That cannot be so! Do you use phpMyAdmin? [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498777/how-do-i-show-the-schema-of-a-table-in-a-mysql-database)

Comment: in your insert query you used only 19 columns

Comment: yeah i know but my table has more than 25 columns and when i;m going in number 20 column the query (statement dosent worrk)