# How to use criteria API to query schema details?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

i have a query to find table details in MySQL **using criteria API in hibernate** Spring, like below **to get 'Auto_increment' from table.**

```
SELECT
  Auto_increment
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'the_table_you_want';
```

1. My first question will be, is it possible to use criteria API to get **information_schema** details'?
2. How to put it in criteria API to get required result ? Because i googled it on this topic i didn't find anywhere, where criteria is used to find schema details.

Comment: take a look [How do I show the schema of a table in a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498777/how-do-i-show-the-schema-of-a-table-in-a-mysql-database)

Comment: @deadman i want how to do it using criteria api in java.

Comment: I doubt you can